# How to mount a bucket from Google Cloud in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I'm trying to mount a bucket into Ubuntu using Gcloud to authenticate me and GCSFuse to mount the bucket.

When i use the command

```
gcsfuse my-bucket /path/to/mount
```

It returns that it couldn't find the default credentials.
So i changed the command to

```
gcsfuse --key-file filekey.json my-bucket /path/to/mount
```

and it says: open filekey.json no such file or directory.

After that i tried typing next to the command `--foreground` and this is what's next:

```
File system has been succesfully mounted.
```

But the terminal doesn't continue ... ?

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Are you running on GCE? If so, you need to include the `storage-full` scope when creating the instance. If not, default credentials won't work.

Comment: As for `--key-file` not working—is `filekey.json` actually there in the working directory? Odd that it works with `--foreground`, but it's expected that in foreground mode it doesn't return. If you're sure the key is there, please file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Try passing to `--key-file` the full path to `filekey.json`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all the fuss with the key json file(s), you can just authorize the SDK to create a default credential for you by running:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```